# To Convert Type Object to Char

Tags: c#

When i am trying to get datarow with the below code, got an error:

```
if (row["FREQ"] != DBNull.Value)
    Char Freq = (Char)row["FREQ"];
```

> Specified cast is not valid.

In Table, the column `FREQ` is declared as below:

```
[FREQ] [char](1) NULL
```

My requirement is to declare it as `FREQ CHAR(1)` as this field contains atleast one characher value. So i cant use string casting as mentioned in the given url.

Comment: Have you tried doing `char Freq = ((string)row["FREQ"])[0];` ?

Comment: Set the breakpoint and check what type is boxed inside.

Comment: if you checked and made sure the type is actually object, you could always  do the following (char)YourObject.ToString();

Comment: @BernardWalters You can´t cast a string to `char`, your code won´t even compile.

Comment: @BernardWalters You do not even have to use compiler to know it will produce compile time error like : _"Cannot convert `string` to `char`'"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try generic extension method `DataRow.Field<T>`

```
var value = row.Field<string>("FREQ");

//If you sure that value is only one character long
var character = value != null ? value[0] : '';
```

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't cast like that, when it comes to data retrieved from database. You should use Convert static class. In your case:

```
string Freq = Convert.ToString(row["FREQ"]);
```

And then you could cast it to char.

Comment: Why shouldn't the OP cast by simply doing (string)row["FREQ"]?

Comment: My experience tells me that this simple casting will not always work and sometimes may give you errors. Convert class however, worked always for me.

Comment: Simple casting will work just fine when your data in the database is a string value, and the OP is already checking for DBNull (which is actually something different to C# null).

Comment: IMO it would be better to call `row["FREQ"].ToString();` and then check `char Freq = resultedString.Length != 1 ? '\0' : resultedString[0];`. Based on the table field structure.

Comment: You're probably right. I just gave "generic" way to do such castings :) Convert class has all the methods. Standard objects just ToString(). And Convert.ToString(obj) calls object's ToString() method.